# Loop record RTSP stream with VLC

Tags: bash, vlc-media-player, rtsp

I am able to save an RTSP stream to a .mp4 file using the following command:

```
/usr/bin/vlc -vvv rtsp://stream_address --sout=file/mp4:/home/test-$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S").mp4 --intf dummy --stop-time=10
```

This generates a playable file, however, the recording does not stop after 10 seconds but only after aborting with Ctrl+C.
Is there a way to loop record this stream, i. e. :

- Record files of a certain length (e. g. 10 minutes) without disruption between them.
- Once a certain size of all files is reached, overwrite the oldest file

Thank you in advance!